# Conteúdo acima das mensages de erro no woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Estou a trabalhar em um site Wordpress e Woocommerce. Foi-me pedido corrigir um erro que acontece quando o user procede para o pagamento sem ter o login feito.

Quando a página é aberta, mensagens de erro aparecem, mas o formulário de login que deveria estar abaixo das mensagens faz um *overlap* às mensagens de erro, e em mobile fica em cima das mensagens.

Alguma ideia de como posso alterar a sua posição?
Cumprimentos, António

Comment: Bem vindo. Dê uma lida na central de ajuda, [como fazer uma boa pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Do jeito que está não será possível ajuda-lo. Além de não conter nenhum elemento (imagen, código) que ajude a resolver o problema, é uma questão que depende muito do contexto do projeto.